# TypeError defining two Array.prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, prototype

I am defining two prototypes for array and one prototype needs to call other like that:

```
Array.prototype.swap = function (x, y) {
      var b = this[x];
      this[x] = this[y];
      this[y] = b;
      return this;
    };
Array.prototype.rotate = function () {
      for (idx in this) {
        nextIdx = idx + 1 < this.length ? idx + 1 : 0;
        this.swap(idx, nextIdx);
      }
      return this;
    };
```

When I run `[1,2,3,4].rotate()` i get an error

```
> TypeError: this.swap is not a function
>     at Array.rotate (/home/user/array.js:11:10)
```

I think it's impossible to use an user-defined prototype inside another, but I want to understand why, and if I'm wrong (it's possible), how can I use? Thanks!

Comment: **never** use `for ... in` to iterate arrays. Your `swap` function is an enumerable prototype property here (also an absolute no-no), so your loop operates on it (and also does string-concatenation on the indices, and generally messes things up majorly). PS: a useful skill to acquire is how to use a debugger - that would tell you quickly, where the problem lies here.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but, so, what is a good way to write this swap function? It's good if I use two splices?

Comment: The `swap` function is not an issue (although more contemporary syntax-sugar ways to express it exist, e.g. `[this[x], this[y]] = [this[y], this[x]]`, and i would not recommend polluting native prototypes at all). The problem is your `for (idx in this) {`. A good test for you would be to do `Array.prototype.swap = function(x, y) { /*... */ }; const test = [1, 2, 3]; for (let idx in test) console.log(idx, typeof idx, Object.hasOwn(test, idx));`

Comment: If you absolutely insist on polluting native prototypes, at least use `Object.defineProperty(Array, 'swap', { value: function(x, y) { /*...*/ } });`, which would make it non-enumerable, non-configurable, and non-writable (per default), but the core problem is still the `for ... in` usage here.

Comment: To come down to the error: your `rotate` at some point swaps the properties "swap" and "0", leading to a (non-prototype-) property "swap", which has the value `4`. This throws in the next iteration (when it tries to swap "rotate"). Also, if you observe what it does, `idx + 1` is string concatenation, and not producing the intended at all.

Comment: In my opinion, i'd prefer stand-alone functions (not residing on a native prototype), and as modern syntax sugar is expressive in this case, no function `swap` at all. This results in e.g. `const rotate = arr => { for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) { const next = (i + 1) % arr.length; [arr[i], arr[next]] = [arr[next], arr[i]]; } return arr; };` (note the `-1` in the loop, my glass-ball tells me you don't want to do the last swap). Then, a shorter way to do this is `const rotate = arr => (arr.push(arr.shift()), arr);` (or `const rotate = arr => { arr.push(arr.shift()); return arr; }`).